# Set theory trees and types.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we had a tree, with one mother (root node) and two terminal sister nodes, such that $x \rightarrow y+z$, and you knew that $x$ had a type of $(e,t)$, and $y$ had a type of $(e,(e,t))$, how do you calculate the type of $z$? I know one answer is that it is of type $(e)$, but I do not know how to come up with this answer properly? And what are the other possible answers?

Comment: Do not edit your questions to become nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

I‘m assuming you are talking about an extensional type theory of the sort used in natural language semantics as in Montague‘s work (essentially, an extensional version of Church‘s simple theory of types), alongside principles that connect syntax trees to the functions in the type theory.

In this case, the daughter nodes $y$ and $z$ cannot be combined by functional application since a type $(e, (e, t)$ function requires a type $e$ entity to apply to, and a type $(e, t)$ function requires a type $e$ entity to apply to. Since functional application only applies between sister nodes of binary branching syntax trees, these types cannot combine.

You would need to apply a so called type shifting function (Partee‘s "iota" function, see http://web.stanford.edu/class/linguist230b/materials/ling230b-handout-04-17-typeshifting.pdf) to shift the $(e, t)$ denotation to a type $e$ entity, which can combine with a function of type $(e, (e, t)$ to produce a type $(e, t)$ function, which would be the denotation of the root node.

Alternatively, you could simply define a special mode of composition, over and above function application, that combines type $(e, t)$ and type $(e, (e, t)$ nodes.

Other type shifting principles could be employed, so long as the functions they represent are definable.